# Data sends to AjAX only on button double click

Tags: php, ajax, button

My AJAX and PHP script is all ok, it functions as it should. My only problem is that the alert function only triggers when the button is double clicked. EDIT: on the first click, the network tab shows all of the data that should be sent with a code of :200

Here is the code that I send to the AJAX

```
<input type="hidden" id="name<?=$product['id'];?>" name="hidden_name" 
value="<?=$product['title'];?>">

<input type="hidden" id="price<?=$product['id'];?>" name="hidden_price" 
class="hidden_price" value="<?=$product['price'];?>">
```

Here is the input that triggers the javascript code

```
<input type="button" class="button" name="cartbtn" id="<?=$product['id'];?>" 
value="Quick Add-to-Cart">
```

Here is the javascript code that sends the data from the inputs to the PHP script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">


 $(document).ready(function(data) {

        $('.button').click(function() {

                var product_id = $(this).attr('id');
                var product_name = $('#name' + product_id).val();
                var product_price = $('#price' + product_id).val();
                var action = "add";

                    console.log(product_id);


                    $.ajax({
                        url: "../PHP_Scripts/quick_cart.php",
                        method: "POST",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: {

                            product_id: product_id,
                            product_name: product_name,
                            product_price: product_price,
                            action: action

                        },
                        success: function(data) {
                            $('#order_table').html(data.order_table);
                            $('.badge').text(data.cart_item);
                            alert("Procuct added to cart");
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
    </script>
```

Can anybody shed some light on what is happening here? I want the product price to get sent to the cart when the button is clicked just once, not twice.

HTTP code is 200; there is no issues with the actual sending of the data, just that the data only gets sent from a double click and not a single click. I know this because the alert only triggers on a double click.

EDIT: HERE IS MY CART CODE:

```
if (isset($_POST["product_id"])) {

$order_table = '';
$message = '';

if ($_POST["action"] == "add") {

    if (isset($_SESSION['shopping_cart'])) {

        $is_available = 0;

        foreach ($_SESSION['shopping_cart'] as $key => $value) {

            if ($_SESSION['shopping_cart'][$key]['product_id'] == 
            $_POST['product_id']) {

                $is_available++;

                $_SESSION['shopping_cart'][$key]['product_quantity'] = 
                $_SESSION['shopping_cart'][$key]['product_quantity'] + 
                $_POST['product_quantity'];
            }

        }

        if ($is_available < 1) {

            $item_array = array(

                'product_id'        => $_POST['product_id'],
                'product_name'      => $_POST['product_name'],
                'product_price'     => $_POST['product_price'],
                'product_quantity'  => $_POST['product_quantity'],
                'product_image'     => $_POST['product_image']

            );

            $_SESSION['shopping_cart'][] = $item_array;

        }

    }

    else{

        $item_array = array(

                'product_id'        => $_POST['product_id'],
                'product_name'      => $_POST['product_name'],
                'product_price'     => $_POST['product_price'],
                'product_quantity'  => $_POST['product_quantity'],
                'product_image'     => $_POST['product_image']

            );

            $_SESSION['shopping_cart'][] = $item_array;

    }

    $order_table .= '

    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr style="color: #000;">
            <th width="40%">Product Name</th>
            <th width="10%">Quantity</th>
            <th width="20%">Price</th>
            <th width="15%">Total</th>
            <th width="5%">Action</th>
        </tr>


    ';

    if (!empty($_SESSION['shopping_cart'])) {

        $total = 0;


        foreach ($_SESSION['shopping_cart'] as $key => $value) {

            $order_table .= '

            <tr style="color: #000;">
                <td>'.$value['product_name'].'</td>
                <td>'.$value['product_quantity'].'</td>
                <td align="right">£'.$value['product_price'].'</td>
                <td align="right">£'.number_format($value['product_price'] * 
                 $value['product_quantity'], 2).'</td>
                <td><button name="delete" class="delete" 
                 id="'.$value['product_id'].'">Remove</button></td>
            </tr>

            ';

            $total = $total + ($value['product_price'] * 
            $value['product_quantity']);

        }

        $order_table .= '

        <tr style="color: #000;">
          <td colspan="3" align="right">Total</td>
          <td align="right">£'.number_format($total, 2).'</td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>

        ';

    }

    $order_table .= '</table>';
    $output = array(

        'order_table'     => $order_table,
        'cart_item'       => count($_SESSION['shopping_cart'])

    );
    echo json_encode($output);
 }
}

?>
```

Comment: Does it realy only get sent on the second click or do you just only see the alert at second click? Did you inspect the network tab on the first click? Does `console.log(product_id)` give correct data on first click? What's the content of possibly returned `data` on first click?

Comment: @Jeff Sorry, I really should have specified; the alert is only activated on the second click. The console.log(product_id) sends correctly, the AJAX only sends on the second click

Comment: So there is literally nothing happening in network tab on first click?

Comment: @Jeff on the first click, the network tab shows that all of the data gets sent correctly with a code of: 200.

Comment: @Jeff do you have any ideas as to what is happening?

Comment: Please comment  the line `dataType: "json",` of your `ajax` code and try to debug the `data` by `console.log(data)`. It might be possible your cart page is not sending proper `json` response.

Comment: @RohitRasela "jquery.min.js:2 XHR finished loading: POST "http://localhost:8015/eCommerce/PHP_Scripts/quick_cart.php"." is what I get on the console. It appears that when the button is clicked, the data is added to the $_SESSION['shoppingcart], but it does not get sent to the PHP script until the second click. Any ideas? thank you for your response by the way

Comment: @RohitRasela "ƒ (e,t){return new w.fn.init(e,t)}" is what happens when I log the data to the console

Comment: Are you sending proper `JSON` response from `quick_cart.php`? Otherwise your alert will not show.

Comment: Can you show your cart page code?

Comment: @RohitRasela i have edited my code to include the cart code. This help is very much appreciated

Comment: Did you write the `session_start();` at the top of the page? If not please add and try again.

Comment: @RohitRasela yes session_start() has been there all along

Comment: @do you have any ideas on what could possibly be going wrong?

Comment: You are not sending `product_quantity` and `product_image ` by ajax post method.

Comment: @RohitRasela Yes I just removed that for Stack Overflow because it was not letting me post it with so much code and so little explanation. The data is all getting added to the session['shoppingcart'] on the first click, but it only gets sent to the PHP script on the second click.

Comment: Your ajax has no issue. There can be problem with your cart page. Please try to debug the php code by allow to show all the php error.